# Setting Up 2FA on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: security, encryption

First off, has anyone else gotten [this setup](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-set-2-factor-authentication-login-and-sudo#comment-form) successfully on their device? I followed the below guide, but cannot login when stating up from a cold boot. My guess is that it has something to do with my Home directory being encrypted when the 2FA code is needed. For now, I had to disable the line in `\etc\pam.d\common-auth`.

Would be happy to get this working, but I figure there may not be many users looking to lock their devices down like this.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Is only your home directory encrypted or is the disk itself too encrypted?

Comment: My home directory is encrypted for a fact (the option on First Run) & I believe the disk is as well: File System: crypt-luks.
Should that be unlocked though once I enter the password at boot? Then the rest of the disk is unlocked, except my home directory. I was thinking that if I can place the necessary files //outside// of my home directory, that might be a way to get around the issue of my home folder being encrypted.

Comment: Well I will try at least to come up with a solution as soon I have a bit time :) Just asking, because i plan on setting up a VM for testing around.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I don't want you to have to go to all that trouble though. I was just hoping to come across someone that was already running it.

Comment: Welll I soon will hopefully :))